# Mocking returning intent function in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, mockito

I have a problem where I want to test the following function:

```
    public static Intent getIntentBasedOnUserType(AppCompatActivity activity, UserType userType) {
    switch(userType) {
        case ENFORCER:
            return new Intent(activity, EnforcerNavigationActivity.class);
        case DRIVER:
            return new Intent(activity, SetTowPlateActivity.class);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Where UserType is an Enum, not important to the question so I left it out.

```
    @Test
    public void getIntentBasedOnUserType() throws Exception {
    Intent enforcerNavIntent = mock(Intent.class);
    ComponentName componentName = mock(ComponentName.class);
    when(componentName.getClassName()).thenReturn(EnforcerNavigationActivity.class.getCanonicalName());
    when(enforcerNavIntent.getComponent()).thenReturn(componentName);
}
```

Now, when I want to test the function getIntentBasedOnUserType I run into plenty of problems, my goal is to basically make sure the Intents target class is correct when supplying with my user types.

1. How do I "mock" the return value?
2. I want to call getComponent().getClassName() on the returned intent, this wont be possible because getComponent() on the returned intent which is not mocked will return null, and the full call will result in a null pointer exception since I can't supply it with a "valid" activity.

How do I solve this?

```
    // Not good either, since I have to set it myself.
    Intent intent = UserType.getIntentBasedOnUserType(null, UserType.ENFORCER);
    when(intent.getComponent()).thenReturn("ClassName...");
```

My goal is basically to do the following:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(null, EnforcerNavigationActivity.class);
    Intent intent2 = UserType.getIntentBasedOnUserType(null, UserType.ENFORCER);
    Assert.assertThat(true, Is.is(intent.filterEquals(intent2)));
```